# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/host

Tags: python, datetime, time, jupyter-notebook, permissionerror

This is Python code for website blocking. I am using Jupyter notebook to run this code. When I run this program I am getting error name as PermissionError.

```py
import datetime
import time
end_time=datetime.datetime(2022,9,22)
site_block=["www.wscubetech.com","www.facebook.com"]
host_path="C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts"
redirect="127.0.0.1"
while True:
    if datetime.datetime.now()<end_time:
        print("Start Blocking..")
        with open(host_path,"r+") as host_file:
            content = host_file.read()
            for website in site_block:
                if website not in content:
                    host_file.write(redirect+" "+website+"\n")
                else:
                    pass
    else:
         with open(host_path,"r+") as host_file:
                content = host_file.readlines()
                host_file.seek(0)
                for lines in content:
                    if not any(website in lines for website in site_block):
                        host_file.write(lines)
                host_file.truncate()
         time.sleep(5)
```

This is the error I get when I run this program:

```
PermissionError
Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [15], in <cell line: 8>()

          9 if datetime.datetime.now()<end_time:
         10     print("Start Blocking..")
    ---> 11     with open(host_path,"r+") as host_file:
         12         content = host_file.read()
         13         for website in site_block:

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 1):

Permission denied simply means the system is not having permission to open the file to that folder.

`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` is writable only by the Administrator. You should run your script in Administrator mode.

EDIT (23/09/2022 - comment):

> I ran your code with pycharm in administrator mode, no error and no output but the file was modified (two extra lines then deleted):

I rewrote the code for testing. Here it is for a different approach:

```py
site_block = ["www.facebook.com", "www.stackoverflow.com"]
host_path = "C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts"
redirect = "127.0.0.1"
with open(host_path, "r+") as host_file:
    for website in filter(lambda website: website not in host_file.read(), site_block):
        host_file.write(redirect + " " + website + "\n")

time.sleep(5)

with open(host_path, "r") as host_file:
    lines = host_file.readlines()
    with open(host_path, "w") as output:
        for line in lines:
            if not any(redirect + " " + website + "\n" == line for website in site_block):
                output.write(line)
```

Tips:

- You can use a boolean to know if you have already updated the file to avoid opening it every 5 seconds.
- You can stop the process after cleaning the file.
- You can also look to run the code with a cron.

Comment: Yes I was run in Administrator mod but when I run my this python file in this mode that  CURSOR only blink not show any OUTPUT or ERORR can you tell me why this happening

Comment: I ran your code with pycharm in administrator mode, no error and no output but the file was modified (two extra lines then deleted).

Answer (score 0):

The PermissionError is caused when you do not have a permission to do something.
The file C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts is protected by the permission. That is why you cannot access to it.
Why don't you run it as administrator?

Comment: Yes.. I was run in Administrator mod but when I run my this python file in this mode the  CURSOR only blink not show any OUTPUT or ERORR can you tell me why this happning